# How can I change the behavior of enter key in pidgin?

Tags: pidgin, instant-messaging

I want to use `enter` as a new line key and send messages using `ctrl+enter`.

How can I rebind the behavior of the keys?

Answer (score 4):

Here is what the [Pidgin FAQ](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#HowdoImakeEntermakeanewlineandCtrlEntersend) tells you to do:

> Locate or create your gtkrc-2.0 file and insert:
>
> ```
> binding "my-bindings"
> {
>     bind "Return" { "insert-at-cursor" ("\n") }
>     bind "<ctrl>Return" { "message_send" () }
> }
> widget "*pidgin_conv_entry" binding "my-bindings"
> ```

The gtkrc file in question is in your home directory. The pidgin-specific gtkrc file is in

```
~/.purple/gtkrc-2.0
```

If it doesn't exist, go ahead and create -- should work.

Comment: Doesn't work in Mint 17.3.

Comment: Somehow worked later. Maybe restart needed.